# Matching anything but "[[2,3],[2,3],[3,7]]"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the [`RegExp.prototype.test()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) in JS to find out if I have anything but an array in the form:

```
"[[2,3],[2,3],[3,7]]"
// or
"[[2,3],[3,7]]"
// there could be any amount of children arrays
```

So I'd like to match anything but an array like `"[[2,3],[2,3],[3,7]]"`.

For example these should match:

```
[2,3,4]
// or
{test: true}
// or
[2,4][[2,3],[2,3],[3,7]]
```

I've tried:

```
/.*(?!\[(?:\[[0-9]+,[0-9]+\])(?:,\[[0-9]+,[0-9]+\])*\])/
```

but this, of course, matches everything, even the array which should not match. How do I solve this? I'd be very grateful for any help!

Comment: _...For example [2,3,4] should match or {test: true} or [2,4][[2,3],[2,3],[3,7]]...._ What is the logic behind that?

Comment: What format are the arrays in? JSON? Are you sure you don’t want to parse them out of a string before trying to match them?

Comment: It becomes quite simple if you take it the other way around. Match anything that **is** a two-dimensional array of numbers. Then just return `!result` (that only works if your string is only suposed to contain a multidimensional array or not, though. Not both)

Comment: @Ry- The array is posted as a string together with a lot of other strings which are just string, not arrays. If I send the array as JSON I assume I have to send everything else as JSON too right?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I will be doing calculations based on these arrays later and if they are not in the correct "format" I will fail to do these calculations...

Comment: If you're going to have to parse the string anyway, in order to perform the calculations, you may as well just parse it and report errors if/when they come up during that parsing rather than checking for errors before parsing.

Comment: @blex That would be a good solution in the scenario you describe but this is my attempt so validate user input: The user posts this array and I need to validate it is in the correct format. But the user could very well post an array in the correct format but also something totally different. (If I'm understanding you correctly...)

Comment: @Ouroborus That sounds like it might actually be the way to go. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Ry- Sorry! I think I misunderstood you before. Parsing before matching them is probably the correct way to go indeed.

Comment: @user73759 But since you said `[2,4][[2,3],[2,3],[3,7]]` should match (it's something "invalid" along with something valid), I'm guessing you only want to match when the input is not "exactly one two dimensional Array of integers only". Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method (using `!`) passes your tests. If that's not what you want, please provide more valid/invalid inputs so that we can help you better:

```js
function isNotATwoDimensionalArrayOfIntegers(s) {
  const regex = /^\[(\[-?\d+,-?\d+\],)*\[-?\d+,-?\d+\]\]$/;
  return !regex.test(s);
}

const demo = s => { const res = isNotATwoDimensionalArrayOfIntegers(s); result.innerHTML += `<span style="color: ${res ? 'green' : 'red'}">${s}  // ${res}</span>\n` } ;

demo("[[2,3],[2,3],[3,7]]");
demo("[[2,3],[3,7]]");
demo("[2,3,4]");
demo("{test: true}");
demo("[2,4][[2,3],[2,3],[3,7]]");
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

View regex explanation on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IfUrvJ/1)

Comment: I guess I misunderstood you the first time. This does indeed solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Good :) Note that I added the possibility of having negative integers with an optional minus (`-?`), and that I'm ensuring that we match if the String contains nothing else, by making sure we go from the start of the String (using `^`) to the end (with `$`). In case you want to ajust that. If you want to allow spaces anywhere, you might also want to `return !regex.test(s.replace(/\s/g, ''));`